# Read DB entries dynamically in TypoScript

Tags: html, database, typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

I have the following setup for my Typo3 installation:

TypoScript:

```
lib.responsiveImage = IMAGE
lib.responsiveImage {
  default = IMAGE
  default{
    file {
        import.current = 1
        treatIdAsReference = 1
      }
      altText.data = DB:sys_file_reference:26:alternative
      titleText.data = current
  }
}
```

Which produces the following output Tag (unneccessary content deleted; important is the alt and the title tag):

```
<img class="img-responsive" srcset="XY.jpg" alt="AltText" title="26" sizes="(min-width: 1200px) 1100px">
```

As you can see, `current` delivers the correct uid of "26". The database query via `DB:sys_file_reference:26:alternative` delivers the correct "AltText".

However -> How could i achieve that dynamically?

I tried something like this

`DB:sys_file_reference:{current}:alternative`

but this doesnt worked. current should be the uid of an FileReference

(Also altText.data = file:current:alternative gives me an `Error: No File Object`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily i found a solution:

```
  default = IMAGE
  default{
    file {
        import.current = 1
        treatIdAsReference = 1
      }
      sourceCollection < tt_content.image.20.1.sourceCollection
      layout < tt_content.image.20.1.layout
      layoutKey = srcset  
      altText.data.dataWrap = DB:sys_file_reference:{current}:alternative
      altText.wrap = |
  }
```

If you use dataWrap the `{current}`works as expected!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the use of the [FILES](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Files/Index.html) element is safer:

```
lib.responsiveImage = FILES
lib.repsonsiveImage {
  references.current = 1

  renderObj = IMAGE
  renderObj {
    file.import.data = file:current:uid
    file.treatIdAsReference = 1

    altText.data = file:current:alternative
    titleText.data = file:current:title
    emptyTitleHandling = useAlt
  }
}
```

Comment: Intersting - this almost works (far better than my other approaches to a FILES object).

Unfortunately i use a sourceCollection to produce responsive images. Whit the IMAGES object, i get the correct output for the <img> tag with the following srcset:
```<img srcset="v1.jpg 120w, v2.jpg 240w, v3.jpg 300w [...]" [...]>```.

With your FILES approach it produces an img tag with ```<img srcset="v1.jpg 120wv2.jpg 240wv3.jpg 300w [...]" [...]>```, so the "," and space is deleted -> Now i have the correct altText but no pictures anymore